# Linq in Inventor API

Tags: api, customization, autodesk-inventor

I have searched for Linq in Inventor API. but, found nothing.
can anyone share the learning link or syntax for it. that would be great

I can implement Linq in Revit API not unable to implement in Inventor API

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ in standard way in Inventor API

This is a sample how to select planar faces from `SurfaceBody`

```cs
Face[] PlanarFaces(SurfaceBody body)
{
    var planarFaces = body.Faces.OfType<Face>().Where(f=> f.SurfaceType == SurfaceTypeEnum.kPlaneSurface).ToArray();
    return planarFaces;
}
```